# Visual studio remote iOS agent configuration error while building cordova app on iOS

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I want to connect to Remote Agent on Mac. I have npm, node.js installed. I have also remotebuild installed and it spits out the remotebuild certificate. I have Xcode installed and active too. But Once I try to connect from VS 2015 Tools for Apache Cordova and input the certificate info I get the following error:

> An error occured to acquire certificate from https://(ip address).

I also tried using unsecure mode and just IP address. When I run remote test on ios terminal i get the following code:
Warning:

> No server modules selected. Defaulting to configuration "modules":
>   {"taco-remote": { "mountPath": "cordova"} } Remote build server
>   listening on [https] port 3000 Please view/edit server configuration
>   at /Users/Bp0_0n/.taco_home/RemoteBuild.config. You many need to run
>   'remotebuild saveconfig' to generate it. You will have to restart the
>   server if you update the server configurations.

I am unable to figure out what is exactly needed to be done? Can any one help me?

Comment: Please try the trouble shooting steps of [this document](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/#certificate). See if the problem could be resolved.

Comment: If your Windows machine cannot even acquire the certificates from your mac running remotebuild --secure false, it means that your mac and Windows machine are not on the same local network, or that your configuration in VS is wrong.